# Set Custom Text in a Custom Alert-dialog (Android-Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, settext

I have this code for my custom dialog:
package com.example.ortel.tagnet;

```
import dev.niekirk.com.instagram4android.requests.payload.InstagramUser;

public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements
    android.view.View.OnClickListener {

  public Activity c;
  public Dialog d;
  public Button yes, no;
  public EditText name;
  public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custon_dialog);
    yes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_yes:
      c.finish();
      break;
    case R.id.btn_no:
      dismiss();
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
    dismiss();
  }
  public String getFirst(String s) {
    name.setText(s);
    return s;
  }

}
```

In my name class, I call...

```
        CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass((Activity) context);
        cdd.getFirst("test");
        cdd.show();
```

I want to set the text (located by the id 'name') to 'test'.

When I run this code, I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference

What is the problem?

***EDIT:***
 Please tell me if you need any more info!

Comment: When you call getFirst(), your dialog is not created yet (there is no UI and onCreate was not called), therefore name is null and you get a NPR.

Answer (score 1):

You try:

```
public void getFirst(String s) {
    name.setText(s);
  }
```

I think you change function name from: [getFirst] to [setNameTitle], your name function not clear.

Comment: So I should change the name to 'SetNameTitle'?

Comment: I tryed changing it to a void. It is still giving me the error

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out!

```
cdd.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        cdd.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.dialog_animation;
        cdd.show();
        cdd.getFirst("test");
```

> cdd.show();

Must come first!

Answer (score 0):

```
cdd.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

At this way you can acess any object by id from your layout file:

```
cdd= new Dialog(Activity.this);
cdd.setContentView(R.layout.layout_file);
cdd.findViewById(R.id.name);
```